# Looping with replaceMatchesInString

Tags: regex, macos, cocoa

Given this string:

*Something* *Else*

the following code requires a loop on replaceMatchesInString to convert both matches to wrap the HTML bold tag around the word otherwise it only matches the first. I can't quite understand why it fails to find the second match without the loop since the API name implies it would work with multiple matches. Is there an error in my regex or my flags?

```
NSString * linkPattern = @"(^|\\s)\\*(.+?)\\*(\\s|$)";
NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:linkPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
while ([regex replaceMatchesInString:modifiedString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [modifiedString length]) withTemplate:@"$1<b>$2</b>$3"] > 0);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression matches the start of the string or a space at the beginning and matches a space or the end of the string at the end. That means the first match ends in a space and the second match starts attempting from the next point in the string: `*Else*` (i.e. after the space).

---

You should be able to use a very simple regex to find the contents between two `*`:

```
\*(.+?)\*
```

Replaced with:

```
<b>$1</b>
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/bE7kL9/1)

---

If you had a reason behind looking for a space around the `*`, let me know in the comments and I will update my answer!

Comment: Ah! It hadn't occurred to me that it would start searching for the second match after the space. You're absolutely right! The spaces are necessary since the asterisks are marking up words so occurrences within a word need to be ignored.

Comment: You should be able to use lookarounds with OSX (not positive), try: [`(?<=\s|^)\*(.+?)\*(?=\s|$)`](http://regex101.com/r/bE7kL9/2)